# Pandas - vectorization with if statements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have such code:

```
#read data source into dataframe
adjustments_list = pd.read_csv('./first_case.csv', encoding = "UTF-16", sep = '\t', parse_dates = ['Date'])

#match F/R and M/X meeting appropriate conditions
#represented by list of sets with two values - each value is id of adjustment, each set is relation
relation_list = []

def func_inner(outer, inner):
    if outer['ASIN'] == inner['ASIN']:
            if outer['reason_code'] == 'F' or outer['reason_code'] == 'R':
                if (inner['reason_code'] == 'M' or inner['reason_code'] == 'X') and (inner['Date'] - timedelta(days = 3)) <= outer['Date'] <= inner['Date']:
                    relation_list.append([outer.name, inner.name])
            if outer['reason_code'] == 'M' or outer['reason_code'] == 'X':
                if (inner['reason_code'] == 'F' or inner['reason_code'] == 'R') and inner['Date'] <= outer['Date'] <= (inner['Date'] + timedelta(days = 3)):
                    relation_list.append([outer.name, inner.name])

def func(x):
    adjustments_list.apply(lambda row: func_inner(outer = x, inner = row), axis = 1)


adjustments_list.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis = 1)
```

How can I switch my approach in order not to use `apply()` function, but vectorization?

I tried to use this resource: [Link](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6), but I don't know how to implement it in my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the vectorization is only for numerical operations. If you want to speed up your code, you could use pandarallel if you use Mac or Linux. If you are on Windows, you could invoke python from WSL
https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel

I am not aware of a naive good tool on Windows for pandas parallelism. Others might help.